# 404 Redirect firing when we receive an error - ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, web-config, http-status-code-404

I have the following values in my web.config:

```
<system.web> 
  <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"
    defaultRedirect="/CARE/Home/Custom404">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="/CARE/Home/custom404"/>
  </customErrors>
</system.web>


<system.webServer>
  <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly">
      <remove statusCode="404"/>
      <error statusCode="404" path="/CARE/Home/Custom404" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
  </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

Works great for our 404 errors (Page Not Found), but for some reason, this is getting triggered when there is an error on the page.

Any ideas as to why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you have the `defaultRedirect` set to your **404** page.

As stated from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.customerrorssection.defaultredirect.aspx):

> The DefaultRedirect specifies the generic error page to activate in case no error custom page exists.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've set the defaultRedirect to point to the 404 error page (this is the same url you set for the redirect for the statuscode=404) on the system.web section.

You might want to set a different page there.